# What's the non-suspending version of `Async/Await` for Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

```
fun nonSuspendingFunction(): Boolean {
    return async(UI) { true }
        .await() // compiler error, can be called only within a suspending function
}
```

Is there a version of `.await()` that can be called outside a suspending function for a `Deferred<T>`? I'd like to block the current thread until the `Deferred<T>` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runBlocking` is what you're looking for.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking

fun blocks() = runBlocking {
    async { true }.await()
}
```

I've just tested the code above with a very simple `main` function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    blocks().let(::println)
}
```

Output:

```
true
```